# Creating a hotfix, welcome message has wrong information

Tags: installshield

I'm creating a hotfix based on an installation file. When I run the hotfix, the first dialog box shows "Welcome to the hotfix for App version . Nothing in my hotfix project refers to this wrong number and I don't see a way to override the value it's putting there. The .msi file in the base image folder did have references to the wrong version number, but I changed them. The hotfix file is still showing the wrong version number. Any idea how I can override this or find where it's pulling this wrong version number from? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open Dialog editor in InstallShield (located under User Interface > Dialogs) and find InstallWelcome dialog. See what its text looks like; maybe there is some hardcoded version referred there. If there is no hardcoded version, see what property is being referred to in the text (e.g.[ProductVersion]), and make sure it's a correct property and it's set to the correct value.